# undo not working after upgrading to Vim 7.4

Tags: vim

I just upgraded to Vim 7.4, but it looks like when I delete the words or sentences by `x` or `D`, and tried to undo it, I cannot undo it with the message: `Already at newest change`. Redo is also not working. Why? I've used OS X built-in Vim (7.3) for many years and have had no issues related to undo/redo.

So how can I fix it? Or in 7.4 undo and redo are defunct? And finally, is it feasible to revert my files to the status prior to the delete?

Comment: Can you reproduce this behavior with running vim with no plugins with `vim -u NONE` ? You should be able to type some text, hit escape, hit x to delete a letter, then the u key to undo.

Comment: It's working now. So does this behavior come from some plugins?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apparently some plugin breaks your undo. You can try to find out which by examining

```
:verbose setglobal undolevels?
```

(It probably yields `-1` since undo isn't working.)

Comment: It returned -123456. I think to look for a plugin causing the issue is quite a painful task, that I may revert to the 7.3... Thanks your answer though.

Comment: Ingo's command should tell you what plugin is doing that, no need to revert to 7.3.

Comment: Doesn't `:verbose` tell you `Last set from ...`? Apart from that, just search all `~/.vim/*.vim` files for `undolevels` (and its short form `\<ul\>`; not too many plugins should touch that.

Comment: Finally, you can resort to _binary partitioning_: Move away one half of your plugins, and check whether the problem is gone. Rinse and repeat...

Comment: -123456 is the local value of the option. Please try again with `:verbose setglobal undolevels`

Answer (score 0):

`u` doesn't mean "delete": it means "undo". If you want to delete something (or rather cut it), use the appropriate command: `d{motion}`.

Comment: Oops. That's a typo. I mean `x`, not `u`. Sorry.

Comment: So I mean, the delete commands like `x` and `D` are working well, but undo/redo commands like `u` and `\r` are NOT.